# Can't change product price with woocommerce_after_calculate_totals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to check some condition and if is true, I want to update the price of all products to 10$.
Everything is working well with this function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_price', 10, 1 );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if(true) { // some condition
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
            $current_product = $val['data'];
            $current_product->set_price( 10 );
        }
    }
}
```

But when the user uses a coupon code the above function stops working, the price doesn't change.
Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have additional code you didn't include? Using the above with a basic order coupon it applied fine. Can you give more specifics?

Comment: Hi, I know what cause the problem, discounts plugin for Woocommerce. Can I do something to avoid that? @MarkTruitt

Comment: Do you have a link to that plugin assuming its free?

Comment: I don't know the exact the name of the plugin right now but I want to know if there is a way that my function will be stronger than the function of the plugin.

Comment: I think the plugin is also uses woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook, that's the problem.

Comment: I'll add an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise or lower the priority. Setting it to 999 would put it as the last thing to run.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'conditionally_change_cart_items_price', 999, 1 );
function conditionally_change_cart_items_price( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if(true) { // some condition
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
            $current_product = $val['data'];
            $current_product->set_price( 10 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's doesn't work

Comment: I'd need the plugin then.

Comment: Maybe I'll turn of that plugin. thanks.